# Why do I get random/wrong output from VBA Select Case?

Tags: excel, vba, select-case

I have a problem with the code below. I've just started to learn this and when I did a simple exercise, it turned out the code is working really randomly.

Sometime nothing is done, sometime only one case is being selected but never the right formatting is applied. I'm quite confused.

Could you please help on this one? ;)

```
Sub Colors()

Dim Check As String
Check = ActiveCell.Value
Range("A2").Select

Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

    Select Case Check
    Case "Red"
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 100, 100)
    Case "Blue"
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 200)
    Case "Green"
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(100, 200, 100)
    End Select

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Highly suggest you give [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) a read.

Comment: It all depends on exactly what your data is on the worksheet and what you expect. Can you provide an example of your data?

Comment: What is the `ActiveCell` address when this procedure is called, and what is its value? Note that `Check` is constant for every iteration of the loop...

Comment: If this is wrong, what is the behavior you are expecting?

Comment: Right now, this code is getting the value of whatever cell you happen to have selected when you start running it, and storing it in `Check`. Then, starting with cell A2, it's coloring the cells of column A with a color, depending on the value that came from that initially selected cell. Once it hits a cell that has a value, it stops. Is  all that what you mean to happen?

Comment: The pattern in the cells (their value) counting from the cell A2 down is: Red Blue Green. What I wanted: if e.g the cell in A5 says Green the entire row 5 should go green. If the cell in A28 says Blue, the entire row 28 should go blue, etc. If I change the Select Case to a bunch of Elseif, it works fine.

Comment: The point is that your code is doing exactly what you wrote the code to do. We're less clear about what you **want** the code to do. What is the data? What result do you want to see, based on the data and the active cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Check` in constant for every iteration of the loop, so `Select Case Check` always evaluates to the same thing, and the outcome of the execution of this procedure depends solely on the value of whatever cell happened to be the `ActiveCell` when the procedure was invoked.

[Avoid Select and Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), but to fix your current immediate problem, you'll want to replace `Check` with `ActiveCell` here, and maybe explicitly invoke its `Value` member:

```
Select Case ActiveCell.Value
```

The `Check` assignment becomes redundant, and now the loop will successively activate a cell starting in A2, evaluate its content, and set the interior color accordingly.

This could also be achieved without any VBA code, using conditional formatting rules applied to the entire row. Consider using conditional formatting instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for this reply. I understand your point and checked - it works, however I don't understand why the `Check` variable with the `ActiveCell.Value` assigned to it gives a different output than the plain `ActiveCell.Value` used within the `Select Case`.

Comment: @JakubTracz `Check` is assigned once, before the loop, and then never reassigned again: it's still holding the exact same cell reference at every iteration - `Check` isn't magically going to "keep up" with what the `ActiveCell` is while the body of the loop constantly activates a different cell. Don't do this to yourself - avoid Select/Activate and you won't have to deal with this kind of issues.